# displaying data from a WFS (vector) layer using getFeatureInfo

Tags: gis, openlayers, geoserver

As the title says... I trying to access that data associated with a vector layer but not having any success.
I get the following error: 
"No QUERY_LAYERS has been requested, or no queriable layer in the request anyways "

I am using geoserver, openlayers and and the script shown below....

```
           map.events.register('click', map, function (e) {
           document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = "Loading... please wait...";
                var params = {
                    REQUEST: "GetFeatureInfo",
                    EXCEPTIONS: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",
                    BBOX: map.getExtent().toBBOX(),
                    X: e.xy.x,
                    Y: e.xy.y,
                    INFO_FORMAT: 'text/html',
                    QUERY_LAYERS: map.layers[1].options.typename,
                    FEATURE_COUNT: 50,
                    Layers: 'monitor:Routers',
                    Styles: '',
                    Srs: 'EPSG:4326',
                    WIDTH: map.size.w,
                    HEIGHT: map.size.h,
                    };
                OpenLayers.loadURL("http://tobagoborn.com:8080/geoserver/wfs", params, this, setHTML, setHTML);
                OpenLayers.Event.stop(e);
            });
```

Any suggestion as to what I am doing wrong would be very much appreciated

Regards
Chris

Comment: Since you don't show the rest of the page, what does `map.layers[1].options.typename` contains? I don't have this value in my OL pages :)

Answer (score 1):

You can ask a WFS to send you data using request=getfeature but if you are using  getfeatureinfo you need a WMS server. GeoServer can provide data through both interfaces but it's best not to mix the two.

In the code you show the most likely problem is that you don't have 2 layers in your map, as the array is numbered from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Is your source URL (the WFS server) actually working? When I [try to go there](http://tobagoborn.com:8080/geoserver/wfs) I get a timeout.

Comment: That's a good question... I am no sure... I've tried use WFS, OWS or WMS on the URL and none works with the script... 

As a test, when I type the following link in my browser, and it successfully returns the data:
http://tobagoborn.com:8080/geoserver/wfs?version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=monitor:Routers&maxFeatures=50&featureID=Routers.4

So I am at a lost as to what's not working

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your map object //
 map = new ol.Map({})

// on click event call displayFeatureInfo method and pass the pixel as a 
   argument in this method  //

   map.on('click', function(event) {
     displayFeatureInfo(event.pixel)
   })


// execute the displayFeatureInfo  method //

var displayFeatureInfo  = function(pixel) {
var features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
   return feature 
})

console.log(features)
console.log(features.R)

// 1. when you see features in console, it is either object or array //
// 2. if got a multiple value on click event then it gives you a array and if 
       got a single value on click event then it gives you a object  //
// 3. now we assume it is object, see (features.R) in console. information is 
      in single single character, then you can concat. //
```

}